Random reduction and NP $\cap$ coNP
If a language $L_1$ in $\sf{NP}$ can be randomly reduced to a language $L_2$ in $\sf{NP}\cap \sf{coNP}$, can we prove that $L_1$ is also in $\sf{NP}\cap \sf{coNP}$?
More specifically, does
$\sf{GI}$ in $\sf{BPP^{L}}$, for some $\sf{L\in NP\cap coNP}$ imply that $\sf{GI \in coNP}$?

Maybe, depending on $L_1$; you can prove lots of things if you try. But if you actually wanted to ask whether all languages $L_1\in\mathsf{NP}$ that are randomly reducible to an $\mathsf{NP\cap coNP}$ language are in $\mathsf{NP\cap coNP}$, then this is not known. On the one hand, anything randomly reducible to $\mathsf{NP\cap coNP}$ is in $\mathsf{AM\cap coAM}$, which equals $\mathsf{NP\cap coNP}$ under plausible derandomization assumptions. On the other hand, any language in BPP is randomly reducible to a language in $\mathsf{P\subseteq NP\cap coNP}$, and $\mathsf{BPP\cap NP}$ is not ...

... known to be included in coNP (e.g., there is an oracle relative to which $\mathsf{BPP=EXP^{NP}}$, see https://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2005/08/extreme-oracles.html , which implies that $\mathsf{BPP\cap NP=NP\nsubseteq coNP}$, as PH cannot even collapse to $\Delta_2^P$ here due to the time hierarchy theorem).

Thank you for your comments, Jeřábek. I have reorganized the question.
